# react-native modify index.android.js no change

Tags: android, react-native

When I first init a react-native project ,I can see new app running in my Android emulator.But when open "index.android.js" in my text editor of choice and edit some lines, select Reload from the Developer Menu .But i can't see any change.When I shut up the server and restart it ,I can see the change.
why?

Comment: react-native 's version is 0.31.0

Answer (score 4):

The Same issue was coming in my project because server was shut down.
 so do not shut down your server while you are making some changes.if you shut down the server again use this command to rebuild and run: `cd android && gradlew` and then

```
cd .. && react-native run-android
```

Comment: U saved my life bro tq so much for saving my time